# Splitting Java string by Alpha and numerics

Tags: java, string, split

I have a set of variables and I want to split them based on the alpha characters and numeric characters in the string.

```
String strPolNuber= AFR123456;
```

So, all my strings would have 3-4 alpha characters at the start and 6-7 numerics at the end.

I want to seperate the alpha and numeric and concatenate them by adding # between them.

```
String strUpdatedString=AFR#123456;
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So you want to put `#` at *place* which has alphabetic character before and digit after it. You can do it with little help of regex [look-around mechanisms](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Code which achieves it can look like

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=\\d)","#");
```

- `(?<=[a-zA-Z])` ensures that there is alphabetic character before matched place, but will not include that character in match itself
- `(?=\\d)` ensures that there is digit after matched place, also digit will not be included in match so it will not be *removed* by anything.

Comment: This is a fine answer which I would like to be able to upvote twice.

Answer (score 2):

What about a regex replace:
`strPolNuber.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z]+)", "$1#")`

If the strings follow such a strict structure this should work. How does it work? Your replace each sequence of chars by the same sequence followed by a "#".

Answer (score 0):

An algorithmic solution would be something like this,

```
private String seperateAlphaNum(String in, int n) {
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  boolean notfound = true;
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    if (notfound && (int)in.charAt(i) < 65) {
      sb.append("#");
      sb.append(in.charAt(i));
      notfound = false;
    } else {
      sb.append(in.charAt(i));
    }
  }
  if (sb.length() == n) sb.append("#");
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another algorithm,

```
static String split(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)))
            return s.substring(0, i) + "#" + s.substring(i, s.length());
    }
    // String doesn't contain numeric part
    return s;
}
```